# While using `aws_iam_access_key` get empty secret key

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I've an existing module, and lately after migrating to terraform 1.0.3 i have been getting the below error, I'm not sure what's wrong here, can someone pls point out why the secret key is empty. The role used to run this module has full IAM access

Module:

```
# Create Credentials for IAM user
resource "aws_iam_access_key" "iam_keys" {
  user = aws_iam_user.iam_user.name
}

# Use External program to run the bash script to get the access_key
data "external" "stdout" {
  program = [
    "bash",
  "${path.module}/credentials.sh"]

  query = {
    access_key = aws_iam_access_key.iam_keys.id
    secret_key = aws_iam_access_key.iam_keys.secret
  }
}
```

Script

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eux

# This script gets the inputs as the json, get the stdin and do an export on stdin to pass to bash script
function parse_input() {
  eval "$(jq -r '@sh "export ACCESS_KEY=\(.access_key) SECRET_KEY=\(.secret_key)"')"
  if [[ -z "${ACCESS_KEY}" ]]; then echo "ACCESS_KEY was null. Check resource aws_iam_access_key,Terraform will fail now!" && exit 1; fi
  if [[ -z "${SECRET_KEY}" ]]; then echo "SECRET_KEY was null. Check resource aws_iam_access_key,Terraform will fail now!" && exit 1; fi
}
```

**Error:** When running terraform plan, getting this error

```
Error: External Program Execution Failed
│
│   with module.user.data.external.stdout,
│   on .terraform/modules/user/main.tf line 16, in data "external" "stdout":
│   16:   program = [
│   17:     "bash",
│   18:   "${path.module}/credentials.sh"]
│
│ The data source received an unexpected error while attempting to execute
│ the program.
│
│ Program: /bin/bash
│ Error Message: + parse_input
│ ++ jq -r '@sh "export ACCESS_KEY=\(.access_key)
│ SECRET_KEY=\(.secret_key)"'
│ + eval 'export ACCESS_KEY='\''AKIA4xxxxxxx'\''
│ SECRET_KEY='\'''\'''
│ ++ export ACCESS_KEY=AKIA4xxxxxxx SECRET_KEY=
│ ++ ACCESS_KEY=AKIA4xxxxxxx
│ ++ SECRET_KEY=
│ + [[ -z AKIA4xxxxxxx ]]
│ + [[ -z '' ]]
│ + echo 'SECRET_KEY was null. Check resource aws_iam_access_key,Terraform
│ will fail now!'
│ + exit 1
│
│ State: exit status 1
```

Comment: Did you import the key? According to the TF docs "This attribute is not available for imported resources" https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_access_key#secret

Comment: No i did not import the resources, Not sure what changed, i downgraded the external provider from latest to v2.0.0 and it worked